# How to use CurrentRegion?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a range corresponding to the region returned by `CTRL-A` when on cell `B3`, which is `B3:J9` for the setup below :

[image]

I have the following code to do so, which uses CurrentRegion in a function :

```
Option Explicit
Function TestY(msg As Range) As Range

    Dim rg As Range, tl As Range

    Set tl = msg.Cells(1)
    Debug.Print tl.Row, tl.Column

    Set rg = tl.CurrentRegion
    Debug.Print rg.Count, rg.Cells(rg.Count).Row, rg.Cells(rg.Count).Column
        
End Function
```

However the debug log below shows that this does not work, `tl.CurrentRegion` is just the same as `msg.Cells(1)` :

```
 3             2 
 1             3             2
```

Why is `CurrentRegion` not working here and how can I fix it to return the same as `CTRL-A` when on `B3` ?

Comment: Probably better to pass the range in question as a parameter. `CurrentRegion` doesn't work in UDFs.

Comment: You could use the [refCurrentRegionBottomRight function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308643/calculating-sub-totals-within-a-dynamic-array-range/66312460#66312460): `Set rg = refCurrentRegionBottomRight(Range("B3"))`.